# Rewriting script from mysql_* to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to rewrite simple insert and update script from `mysql_*` to `PDO`. I think I've made it most of it but there is something that I can't understand how will be in PDO. This is the mysql source.

```
if(!empty($_POST["image_id"])) {
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$query = "INSERT INTO ipaddress_vote_map (ip_address,image_id,vote_rank) VALUES ('" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "','" . $_POST["image_id"] . "','" . $_POST["vote_rank"] . "')";
$result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
if(!empty($result)) {
    $query = "SELECT SUM(vote_rank) as vote_rank FROM ipaddress_vote_map  WHERE image_id = '" . $_POST["image_id"] . "' and ip_address = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "'";
    $row = $db_handle->runQuery($query);

    switch($_POST["vote_rank"]) {
        case "1":
            $update_query ="UPDATE images SET votes = votes+1 WHERE image_id='" . $_POST["image_id"] . "'";
        break;
        case "-1":
            $update_query ="UPDATE images SET votes = votes-1 WHERE image_id='" . $_POST["image_id"] . "'";
        break;
    }

    $result = $db_handle->updateQuery($update_query);   
    print $row[0]["vote_rank"];
 }
}
```

And this is my try -> PDO

```
if(!empty($_POST["image_id"])) {
include 'misc/database.inc.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$pdo = Database::connect();   

$query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO ipaddress_vote_map (ip_address,image_id,vote_rank) 
                          VALUES (:remote_address, :image_id, :vote_rank)");    
$query -> execute(array(
                    "remote_address"    => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                    "image_id"          => $_POST['image_id'],
                    "vote_rank"         => $_SERVER['vote_rank']
));    

if(!empty($query)) {
    $query = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT SUM(vote_rank) as vote_rank FROM ipaddress_vote_map  WHERE image_id = :image_id and ip_address = :remote_address");
    $query -> execute(array(
            "remote_address"    => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            "image_id"          => $_POST['image_id']                
    ));

    switch($_POST['vote_rank']){
        case '1':
        $update_query = $pdo -> prepare("UPDATE images SET votes = votes+1 WHERE image_id= :image_id");
        $update_query -> execute(array(
            'image_id' => $_POST['image_id']
        ));
        break;
        case '-1':
        $update_query = $pdo -> prepare("UPDATE images SET votes = votes-1 WHERE image_id= :image_id");
        $update_query -> execute(array(
            'image_id' => $_POST['image_id']
        ));
        break;            
    }
    $result = $pdo->updateQuery($update_query); 
    print $row[0]["vote_rank"];
}
Database::disconnect();    
}
```

What I can't understand how to do is after the INSERT statement do I need something like this

```
$result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
```

and how will be in PDO? Because I work with the `$query` - `if(!empty($query)) {...` and I'm not sure that this is right. Also the last part

```
$result = $pdo->updateQuery($update_query);  
print $row[0]["vote_rank"];
```

How will be in PDO?

Is it right the PDO part? I mean do I rewrite it ok?

Comment: May I suggest an ORM, something simplistic to get you started, perhaps [Idiorm](https://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It will really cut down on errors in generals and code deployment.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've also thinking for something like this but I want first to understand some simple scripts and how things are working. This is seems to be a bit advanced for me at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check how many rows were inserted with

`$result->rowCount()` if it is equal to 0 then query failed.

in your case

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
```

Also as @Andrew suggested ORM is better and more logical approach check Doctrine/Propel ORM they are really great libraries to work with DB.

From manual:

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

Comment: `if($query->rowCount() > 0)` to replace `if(!empty($query))`?

Comment: Ok, and what about the last part - `$result = $pdo->updateQuery($update_query);`

Comment: Check edited answer rowCount() will work with DELETE INSERT OR UPDATE query s so you need do the sam for `$pdo->updateQuery()`

Comment: So `$result = $pdo->updateQuery($update_query);` become just `$query->rowCount();`